# Why is wifi deactivated in Lubuntu?

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu

I've given a very old laptop to an aquintance of mine. I tested wifi at home and it worked fine, but now he can't get it to work in his home. I just skyped with him (by phone) and he showed me his screen, which I pasted below with some translations.

And I really don't understand this, the top thing says the wifi network is disabled, but the bottom thing has a checkmark next to "Activate wifi network". How should this work?

[image]

Comment: What does: `rfkill list all` report?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Without more info I can only guess the WiFi is disabled by hardware switch.